# How to set render engine in blender?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, game-engine, interface, blender-internal-render-engine

I'm new to blender. How do you change the render engine?

According to this video, the button should be along the top. I've searched google, and the blender documentation with no luck.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H_d7aT39mHQ

Comment: Could you upload a screenshot of how your screen looks? Is there a "back to previous" button?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For version 2.8

Use the render properties section of the scene editor.

[image]

There you can find the options that are available in your particular version.

[image]

For versions up to 2.79, you need to be on the info window

[image]

then select your render engine

[image]

**Note that blender internal and the game engine have been removed starting with version 2.8.**

Comment: Thanks, I just figured that out after a whole lot of clicking.