# Object Info Node

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, node-editor

Is this missing in Blender 2.73?  I cannot find it.  I looked in the Input menu, but it's not there (using youtube tutorials)

Answer (score 4):

First you are have to be [using cycles](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/15681/2217). Also the node editor has to be editing the [*Shader nodes*](http://www.blender.org/manual/composite_nodes/introduction.html#accessing-and-activating-nodes).
The shader node button is highlighted in the image below. 
[image: node editor header]
Then the *Object Info* node will show up. <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> > *Input* > *Object Info*.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

On the Material Nodes

[image]

it's on Input-> Object_Info Node.

[image]