# can't find image texture node in node editor

Tags: node-editor

[image: node editor add menu]
As you can see screen capture I took, I can't find any image texture in the add menu.
All the videos I saw, there was an image texture node in *Add* > *Texture* > *Image Texture*, but I even can't find the first depth.

version is 2.78

Comment: in the future please crop your images.

Comment: Most likely the "tutorial" you are watching is meant for the cycles render engine. To change render engines please read: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15681/how-to-set-render-engine-in-blender

Answer (score 6):

Based on the node I see, you are in Blender Internal Render. If you switch to Cycles and add a new material, you will find the Add > Texture > Image Texture.

Comment: Found at top of the screen, right side of the **Browse Scene**

Answer (score -1):

From the Image I can see that the Node tree type to display and edit option is set to display the **Compositing** or Compositing nodes. You wont be able to see the Image Texture option in the add menu until you set the Node tree type to display and edit to **Shader** or Shader nodes.

[image]

Comment: Node tree type to edit shown in the image from the original post is set to Material nodes, not compositing. The OP have set their render engine to Blender Internal which is already mentioned in the anwer provided