# Material options missing?

Tags: modeling, interface

So, i want to add some water to my scene. But i´ts the second video i am watching with options displayed that are missing in my blender. Am i missing something? It´s about the materials...
[image: how ot should look]

this is how it should look.
[image]

and how it looks on my blender. There are far less options. Where is Lambert for example? Can someone suggest another video/way to do it?

Comment: At the very top of the screen you can see that you are using cycles render engine and the tutorial is set for blender internal. Read: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15681/how-to-set-render-engine-in-blender

Answer (score 1):

The difference in the material's options are in the renderer engine. On the video you are seeing, the author is using Blender Render (also named Blender Internal), and you are using Cycles. If you change to Blender Render

[image]

the options will be the same, yet I would suggest you to search for a tutorial using Cycles. About Lambert, is a kind of algorithm for reflections, or how the way the light gets diffused in the object. See the follofing image for examples on other kinds of similar algorithms, and you'll understand what i'm saying: http://what-when-how.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/tmpcd00152_thumb.png