# Material Menu in 2.79 with old model

Tags: materials

I have a model from a previous version of Blender, and the more advanced material options are not available from the menu.  If I do a "Load Factory Settings" then the new material options show, but not with the old model loaded.  Can I get an old model to work with the new material options?

BTW: I'm looking to control the alpha channel.

[image: Material Panel with old model]

This is how it looks after "Load Factory Setting"
[image]

Comment: Which options specifically are you missing? How are you trying to access them?

Comment: All of the transparency options are gone.

Comment: You are looking at the material settings of different render engines. Read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/72868/material-options-missing

Answer (score 0):

cegaton is correct.  Thanks.

Now I have to figure out how to get access to the alpha channel in Cycles.  Looks much harder.

-doby

Comment: if you are talking about the alpha of the overall material then all you need to do is add a Mix Shader and a Transparent Shader.