# Ply color can't be rendered in blender

Tags: rendering, color

I have a scanned 3D model with color information in PLY format. 
However, I failed to add this information to render image in blender.

Someones shows that the attribute node can do the job. But I even can't find this node in 2.78 in node editor.

It seems that the software changes a little bit. The only option for input are

coordinates

curve time

Image

Texture

I tried the material mode, still there is not attribute node. 
[image]

Can someone help me in this?

[image]

Comment: You are looking at the texture nodes, the [material nodes](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/node_editor/introduction.html#node-tree-types) have the attribute node, that is assuming you are using cycles.

Comment: I tried the material, still couldn't find the attribute node. I have updated the post with the input option available.  Could you provide me a link with detail procedure to do this?

Comment: The attribute node is used in cycles, you seem to be using blender render. See: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15681/how-to-set-render-engine-in-blender

Comment: Thank you. That is correct. I also find a way to add color to material. In material option, we can select the using vetices color option.