# Import & render PLY with color in the latest Blender 2.8

Tags: cycles-render-engine

In the latest version of Blender (2.8), I can't find the option "vertex color paint" in *cycles* mode to render the PLY mesh with color.
I can show the PLY mesh color with "Vertex Paint" mode but when I press `F12` to render, the output is still a grayscale image. 
I have been googling a lot but still can't find a proper solution for Blender 2.8.

Below are some links I found:

- [Ply color can't be rendered in blender](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/85059/ply-color-cant-be-rendered-in-blender)
- [Import PLY doesn't display vertex colors](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36783/import-ply-doesnt-display-vertex-colors)
- [How to display and use Vertex Color from OBJ model](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/90890/how-to-display-and-use-vertex-color-from-obj-model)

Here is the PLY mesh file I tried: https://www.dropbox.com/s/e9hvbu0iq0tpafn/obj_000006.ply?dl=0

Comment: Have you tried the material setup from your first link?

Comment: It's the material setup from this link that needs to be applied https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36783/import-ply-doesnt-display-vertex-colors