# Couldn't get the mix shader

Tags: materials, shaders

[image]

Couldn't get the mix shader and the proper node editing only few options are available what to do

Comment: If you are looking for shaders you need to change to cycles. See: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15681/how-to-set-render-engine-in-blender

Answer (score 1):

That is because you are in blender render mode.You need to switch it to Cycles render mode.[image]