# I'm having trouble baking material colors into a image texture (faces with wrong colors)

Tags: node-editor, texture-baking

I'm currently doing a project where I convert Voxel models into a model I can export into another format.  I've gotten pretty far, but I've reached a wall.

First, here's a screen of my model. Each square is its own material and is colored that way on the materials pane:

[image: Imported model]

Okay, I unwrap my UV, and create an image for baking.  As you can see the UV is just a bunch of squares, but that's what I want (and I also tried `remove doubles` with `Limited dissolve` and getting a prettier UV, but the results are the same as shown later on).

[image: My UV]

I have to, as seen other help-questions, create a new Image Texture Node for *each* material (there is a material for each color so there are about 80):

[image: The highlighted Node is the texture node I added.]

After adding all those nodes, I bake using the following settings because I only want the material color to come through (no lighting):

[image: Bake Settings]

And here's my end result after the bake (this is after I reassign all vertices to a new material that uses my new baked texture image:

[image: Garbage!]

You can clearly see that there was a disconnect between the location of the faces, and their material color during the bake.  I have no idea what I did wrong, and why this happened.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You could duplicate the object, create there material with the final texture to bake to and bake with Selected To Active selecting main object first, no need to create 80 Image Texture nodes. Though so far your Image Texture node with "Bake" image has only 30 users, probably not all images are baked to it. Also I don't understand those nodes in the editor - Material and Output nodes seem to be from Blender Internal, while you are baking definitely in Cycles.

Comment: Okay, first, thanks for replying!  I do not really understand the "blender internal" versus "cycles".  I'll google it, but the only reason I switch between them is because a guide on baking a texture with material color told me to.  I'll try your first suggestion now...

Comment: EDIT: I think it worked.  When I tried the first time I selected the New object first, but when I selected the old object first, baked with "texture" it looks like it worked!

Comment: Regarding Cycles <> Blender Internal - https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15681/how-to-set-render-engine-in-blender. These are different rendering engines with different material setups which aren't compatible. Hence it was unexpected for me to see material nodes from one render engine in material nodes from another render engine, this wouldn't work. I'm glad you found a way to make it working. You can post an answer outlining what you did to solve it.

Comment: @MrZak  I'll update is as an answer then. Thank you so much, you saved the day.  The VR Doom community thanks you!