# My blender has not one option that I really need

Tags: cycles-render-engine

Actually I am working on blender 2.79 and I want to rig a car and I completed some steps through video tutorial which I found on youtube.

Now I need one option which is cycles setting in object tab of properties panel, but in my blender there is no option of cycles setting.

What to do for that, should I download any plugin?

[image: Screenshot of Video Tutorial]

[image: Screenshot of my Blender]

Comment: At the moment, you're using the Blender renderer, so there are no Cycles settings -(The panel is context-sensitive.) Switch to Cycles in the top bar of your window.

Comment: maybe related/duplicate: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15681/how-to-set-render-engine-in-blender

Answer (score 3):

You must change **Blender Render** to **Cycles Render** to enable it.

See it at the top menu bar.

Image below:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You're not in Blender Cycles—these are "cycles settings." Change your render engine to Cycles and it should show up.