# Denoise missing in 2.79

Tags: edit-mode

Currently I am using Blender 2.79, checked everywhere, and I cannot find denoising. I checked in the correct spots, but can't find it.

Am I supposed to download it from https://www.blender.org/download/releases/2-79/?

I already looked at the answers and they didn't help. I am using 2.80 and 2.79. I tried both and they didn't have denoising.

I checked answers and this is all I found: 
https://gyazo.com/125bd2cb86d2b8207e6d7c844109f646

Comment: If you don't want this marked as a duplicate, actually add a screenshot or something that shows it isn't. Also check that you actually have cycles selected as the renderer in 2.79

Comment: If you feel the linked answer is not a duplicate please edit your question and post some screenshots showing evidence of the place where denoising should be and is not. We can then reopen the question so you can get a proper answer, otherwise we won't be able to provide any meaningful help.

Comment: The image linked on the post (is it really that hard to [make the images part of the question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491)) shows settings for blender render, not for cycles, as noted on the first comment. Densoiser cannot be used in blender render, it can only be used in cycles. So, yes, the questions is a duplicate. To change render engine read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15681/how-to-set-render-engine-in-blender