# Animation is rendered in Eevee instead of cycles

Tags: rendering

I did an animation which i rendered to PNG using EEVEE for preview/testing purposes and after deciding i was happy with it, i tried rendering with cycles and it rendered in EEVEE.

I thought maybe i needed to close and restart Blender, and even deleting the original EEVEE renderings from the folder but i ended with the same result, I know it's probably only a schoolboy error but i'm lost. Thanks in advance

Comment: Just to be sure, you've selected Cycles as render engine, the output path is set to the directory you are checking and the overwrite option is enabled?

Comment: Restarting blender is not going to change the settings for render. You have to set the render to whatever engine you want.

Comment: Read: [How to set the render engine in blender](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15681/how-to-set-render-engine-in-blender/15682#15682)

Comment: Hi, yes I've made sure that the render engine is set to cycles and overwrite is checked.

Comment: Did you use the viewport render animation instead of the regular render animation ? View > Render Animation instead of the regular Render Animation (CTRL+F12) ?

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me, here is how I fixed it.

I rendered an animation in EEVEE to see what it was like and then created a video using the video sequencer.

Next day, I decided to do a Cycles render, but regardless of settings it always seemed to render an EEVEE render for both single image and animation.

Then I realised, I still had the EEVEE png files referenced in the Video Sequencer.

I deleted the strip, and then Hey Presto, I got Cycles rendering back!